# How could set the java.library.path in Linux from I am trying JNI

Tags: java, c, linux, path, java-native-interface

I follow this [JNI ref](http://web.archive.org/web/20120419230023/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html) to call c function from java.

In final step, I got follow error msg after I type **java hellojni** :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no helloJni in
>
> java.library.path
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
>
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>
> at HelloJni.(HelloJni.java:13)

I try to set up the java.library.path, so I type **java -Djava.library.path=. HelloJni**

But this not works for me, I still got same error message.

Also, I try **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/sybase/IQ-16_0/jim_samples/udf/hellojni**, but is still no work.

Comment: did you load the library in your Helloxxxx.java
static {
         System.loadLibrary("Helloxxxx");
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like path issue, where your **libhellojni.so** is not found in "sybase/IQ-16_0/jim_samples/udf/hellojni" **directory**.

Remember '**lib**' prefix is important in your xxx.so file (if you are running this in Linux), just **hellojni.so** will not work.